# Call Browser window resize method from IFrame

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iframe, resize

I want to call browser window resize method using jquery from with in iframe.

I have used below script which is called on window Resize , but it is not working if that page is included in iframe , and parent window browser get resized

Page name : test.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).resize(function () {
            alert("hi resize called");
        });
    </script>
some HTML code here.....
```

Page name : iframeTest.aspx

```
<iframe style="width:300px;height:300px" src="test.aspx" ></iframe>
```

Now when I run `"iframe.aspx"` on browser , and then browser get resized , then I want to call resize method within `"test.aspx"`

Can anybody have idea on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test.aspx you can handle the parent window resize event like this:

```
parent.window.onresize = function(event) {
    ...
}
```

That should fire when the parent window is resized.

Comment: what happens, if the original document get's unloaded (by clicking a new link) - shouldn't there be a unsubscribe action to avoid any leaks?

Answer (score 1):

Add this `js` in your `test.aspx` page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    parent.window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
        //do something
    });
});
```